# i have an issue with progress indicator as the state not updared by the indicator while sending HTTP request

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I had an issue with updating my state and show an indicator for the user while sending HTTP request the if condition in the column widget not checked

[image]

Comment: SizedBox(height:10),
          
          if (_isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator() else RaisedButton(
                 onPressed:(){_saveForm();},
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('SignUp'),
                color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,)
            
        ],));
  }
}

Comment: in every update for the state it shows only the button